# SQL Server: Merge in iterations

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge, sql-server-2017

I have to merge millions of rows into a table. The target table has an AFTER UPDATE trigger. The whole process is consuming a lot more memory than I'd like to allocate, and tempdb is eating up disk space.

I'd like to have the MERGE command run in batches of 100,000 records at a time. With SET ROWCOUNT being deprecated and cursors being inefficient, I'm not sure what the best approach for this would be.

Comment: I don't see how replacing an `update` with `merge` is going to change the performance of the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

A set oriented approach would be best way to run the query efficiently. So what you are doing seems just fine to me. If it consumes temp db etc, would need to know if you are doing any row by row operations which is slowing down. Generally a MERGE is a single statement and therefore is efficent.

The other things to consider is, if you got indexes on the destination table, then you could drop those indexes and then run the MERGE followed by recreating the indexes.

Coming to your question, you can split up into batches by using the mod operator and running the MERGE in a loop

eg:

```
declare @i int
select @i=count(*)/10 from source


while @i>0
begin
   merge
    into dest d
   using (select *
            from source
           where id%10000=i --here id is the primary key of the source table
          ) s
      on d.id=s.id
    when matched
     set ...
    when not matched
     insert...
    ...rest of the insert/update logic here    

    set @i=@i-1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try WHILE loop

```
DECLARE @I INT = 1
WHILE (@I > 0)
BEGIN
    ;MERGE INTO Dst USING (
         SELECT TOP 1000
         FROM Src
         WHERE NotUpdated
    )
    ...
    
    SET @I = @@ROWCOUNT
END
```

Comment: in order to not merge the same 1000 rows over and over again, you use
WHERE NotUpdated.
How would you implelement that on Src, in the middle of a Merge?

Comment: It depends on the usecase. You can join Dst table to check if the row was updated. Advantage of this solution is that there is no problem with adding records to Src or Dst during cycle.

Comment: That's an interesting idea.
Question: would the trigger be fired once each iteration for the loop is executed, or (as I fear), only after the entire transaction is run?

Comment: I tested it, and the trigger is fired for every iteration of the loop.